# How to determine stability of nonlinear diffusion equation using explicit finite difference scheme?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences

I'm trying to determine stability criteria for a particular case of nonlinear diffusion
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(g(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right),
$$
using finite differences. For linear diffusion [Von Neumann Stability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) can be used to get the result
$$
\nu \frac{\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2} \leq \frac{1}{2},
$$
but I'm not sure where to start for nonlinear diffusion since the same technique does not appear to work. Any references of where to look would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not try a regularized energy minimization approach? They are almost guaranteed to be nicely behaved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with energy minimization approaches to numerics. I'm slightly familiar with using minimization approaches to prove uniqueness for some differential equations, but how are they used numerically?